# Get the selected button titles from a UIAlertAction sheet added to a UIAlertViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created action sheet using Objective-C. When I want to get the selected button title, I got stuck. Please help me.
(I know there is a delegate method to get the titles of actions. But it is deprecated in iOS 8.0+.) 
This I my code. My requirement is to get the selected title and update it to a text field.

```
NSArray *subjectType = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Customer Service",@"Product Info",@"Deals",@"Special",@"Others", nil];

    UIAlertController *subjectSheet = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Subjects" message:@"Select a prefered subject" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];


    for (int i=0; i<subjectType.count; i++) {
        UIAlertAction *myalertAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:[subjectType objectAtIndex:i] style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

        }];


    [subjectSheet addAction:myalertAction];
}
```

Comment: `UIActionSheet` class itself has been deprecated as of iOS 8. Please show us your code.

Comment: what is the point of getting title? If you could explain so that we could answer correctly

Comment: @ozgur,  I edited my question. you can see my code

Comment: @SyedAliSalman I want to update a text field using the selected button title. so I need to get the selected button title

Comment: can you please check if my answer satisfy you?

Answer (score 1):

Try the title property of `UIAlertAction`

```
 UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title"
                                                               message:@"message"
                                                        preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
[alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                          style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                              NSLog(@"%@",action.title);
                                          }]];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:true completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do some thing like below to implement what you wanted to achieve

```
NSArray *subjectType = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Customer Service",@"Product Info",@"Deals",@"Special",@"Others", nil];

UIAlertController *subjectSheet = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Subjects" message:@"Select a prefered subject" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];


for (int i=0; i<subjectType.count; i++) {
    UIAlertAction *myalertAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:[subjectType objectAtIndex:i] style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
          [self takeActionAccordingToString:action.title];
    }];


[subjectSheet addAction:myalertAction];
[self presentViewController:subjectSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
}
-(void)takeActionAccordingToString:(NSString *)actionTitle{
if([actionTitle isEqualToString:[yourArray objectAtIndex:0]]){
//you can take action here
}
if([actionTitle isEqualToString:[yourArray objectAtIndex:1]]){
//you can take action here
}
if([actionTitle isEqualToString:[yourArray objectAtIndex:2]]){
//you can take action here
}
if([actionTitle isEqualToString:[yourArray objectAtIndex:3]]){
//you can take action here
}
if([actionTitle isEqualToString:[yourArray objectAtIndex:4]]){
//you can take action here
}
//etc....
}
```